# Create a JSON file while calling a function

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a .json file dynamically whenever data will be inserted and I'm using the following function and while I'm calling this function from another function, the clientList.json file is not creating with data though the file is under json folder,how do I do this ?-

```
<?php
public function getClientJson(){
    $data=$this->model->fetchJson();
    $fp=fopen('../../json/clientList.json', 'w+');
    fwrite($fp,json_encode($data));
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: Have any error messages? You have permission to modify the file?

Comment: no error message,data is inserting but no json data is creating

Comment: have you tried `file_put_contents('/path/to/json', $your_json);`

Comment: Edit:::    file_put_contents('../../json/clientList.json', $data)

Answer (score 0):

You should first make sure that the `json_encode($data)` call, actually contains json.

Secondly, check if the path you specified for the `fopen` is actually the path, you think you are writing to.

Where in your file structure are your `getClientJson` specified? And from where is it called?

```
Also, make sure that you have write permission to that specific folder.
```

You could try using the `'c+'` flag instead of `'w+'` -Just to test.

Are you handling errors? Are you getting any?

If not, try adding this to the top of your document

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

And see if any errors are present.

---

try replacing your whole fopen / fclose block with this

```
file_put_contents('../../json/clientList.json', $data);
```

Does this work?

Comment: simply no effect,as it is,any other sollution to create json file dynamically?